# Understanding Pole-zero plot

Tags: signal-processing

I'm having troubles understanding the following plot:

[image]

Where z_0 = 0 and z_\infty = 0 are the zero points and z = +i0.5; z = -i0.5 are the poles.

I know that this would be interpreted as *stable* it the poles would be on the left side/their real value was negative. Since their real part is zero I am not sure if this system is stable or not.

Another thing I don't understand is when this system is supposed to be causal. The unit circle is inside the ROC (shaded area) so does this mean it is causal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your stability criteria wrong: left/right plane criteria are for analog systems, i.e. when the transfer function is a Laplace transform (s-domain).

When you're dealing with discrete-time systems, and hence you're using the [Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform), the system is stable if all the poles are strictly inside the unit circle. Therefore your system is stable.

**EDIT** (Due to more accurate scrutiny)

From the drawing you posted, it's not clear whether its *Region of Convergence* (ROC) is the shaded area outside the smaller circle, or its inner (unshaded) area. In the former case (ROC is the shaded area) the unit circle is well inside the ROC, therefore the system is stable and causal. On the other hand, if the ROC is the smaller circle's interior, then the system would be anti-causal and unstable.

Please note that the knowledge of just the transfer function (or, worse still, just its poles, as in this case) is insufficient to determine whether the system is causal or not. You need to know its ROC as well.

To recap:

- Stability is achieved if the unit circle is inside the ROC.
- Causality is achieved if the ROC reaches infinity.